# Clear spaces and put on vector

Tags: android

How can i get the values from edit text without getting the spaces between each one of them , and fill up a vector by these values
For example if the input on the edit text is: 5 500 60 90
I want to fill up a vector by these valuse when click on buttun

Comment: On button-click get the text, split by " " and add the segment to your array - what's the issue, excately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the string by calling `editText.getText().toString()` and then call on `split(" ")` method. This gives you an array of strings separated by the space character. You can then parse each string from that array and get the values and then build the vector